# Nginx: possible to resolve DNS dynamically in location block?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Currently I am using Nginx with Kubernetes. In my Nginx conf file I have the following proxy pass:

```
location ~ /myPath/([\w-]+)/resources {
    rewrite ^/myPath/([\w-]+)/resources/(.*)$ /myNewPath/$1/resources/$2 break;
    proxy_pass http://$1;
}
```

Currently Nginx complains that it is unable to resolve the $1 at runtime to perform the proxy_pass (despite us having our SkyDNS resolver specified i.e. resolver 10.250.0.5 valid=5s).

We need this to be done dynamically because at Nginx start up the value of $1 may not be known and must be resolved when requested.

Is Nginx capable of doing this dynamic DNS resolution on the fly?

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/resolver

Comment: Thanks for that, I have already taken a look at the documentation (as I mentioned that I'm already using the resolver directive in my conf).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Nginx [can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743609/dynamic-proxy-pass-to-var-with-nginx-1-0) [dynamic resolution](http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html).

However, your regular expression may be flawed. The regex of `([\w-]+)` would /not/ match a dot character when used with the PCRE engine. You can test that on https://regex101.com/

According to the [PCRE docs](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> A "word" character is an underscore or any character that is  a  letter
>          or  digit.

So your regex would work for values like "short-host-name", but not "fully-qualified.example.com".